# R Leaflet renders only 6 out of 650+ points on map

Tags: r, leaflet

I have been using Leaflet before for a different dataset, which was from a CSV file. This dataset however, is in a Data Frame, which has 675 rows (some lat and lon are NA values, but most are there).

The problem is that I would expect there to be at least 500 or more points on the map, but it seems to render only about 6. Anyone experienced this before?

```
renderUiMeetup <- function(data){
  return (leaflet(data) %>% addTiles('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png') %>%
            setView(5, 52.37, zoom = 11) %>%
            addCircles(~results.venue.lon, ~results.venue.lat, weight = 1, radius=2,
                       color="#000", stroke = TRUE, fillOpacity = 0.8))
}
```

When I check the `data`, it is indeed the dataframe with 675 rows. This function is called in a reactive functions, if that matters (I assume not, since each time I see the dataframe inside the function still returns what it should)

Any help appreciated, do not know where this is coming from ..

**EDIT: Some data (meetup data)**

```
                  results.venue.address_1                 results.venue.name results.venue.lon results.venue.id
1                      Amstel 1 Amsterdam        Raadzaal Stadhuis Amsterdam          4.900240         24631310
2                               16 Notweg                     FitClub Bergen          4.699218         24632049
3                               16 Notweg                     FitClub Bergen          4.699218         24632049
4                            Nieuwmarkt 4                       Waag Society          4.900210         23744775
5                            Overtoom 301         Anamorphic Studio in OT301          4.865707         16443062
6                        Langs de Akker 3                          Emergohal          4.879670         23816542
7                                    <NA>                               <NA>                NA               NA
8                 Goeman Borgesiuslaan 77                 Ibuildings Utrecht          5.113864         19126412
9                          Amstelstraat 2 Vapiano Restaurant - Rembrantplein          4.910965         12762372
10                    Amstelveenseweg 130                        All4Running          4.855405         23844308
11                           Overtoom 301                              OT301          4.865604          6736512
12 Ceintuurbaan 338, 1072 GN Amsterdam |                   The Rialto Cinema          4.893891         24690797
13                       Weteringschans 6                           Paradiso          4.884215           698679
14                   Singel 165A 1012 WE                       Het Spinhuis           4.889594         24224032
15                    Recht Boomssloot 52                    De Boomsspijker          4.903769          1110122
16                          Oosterpark 10                       Bar Bukowski          4.917633         21271582
17                Nieuwe Achtergracht 170                               Crea          4.912870          9152402
18                    James Wattstraat 10             Basisschool 'Spectrum'          4.925560         23633711
19                      Volmolengracht 13                  MakerSpace Leiden          4.493560         23445132
20                 Lizzy Ansinghstraat 88                   Sporthal de Pijp          4.893200         23594478
21                      ketelhuisplein 41                    WG cursusruimte          4.869719          1500646
22                              Jansdam 3          Mick O'Connells Irish Pub          5.122060           702533
23                             Spui 25-27                            Spui 25          4.889688          2549081
24          Arthur van Schendelstraat 650                        HNK Utrecht          0.000000         24251942
25       Vondelpark 6B, 1071 AA Amsterdam                  Kinderkook cafe            4.864780         23666288
   results.venue.lat results.venue.repinned results.venue.phone results.venue.address_2 results.rating.count
1           52.36768                  FALSE                <NA>                    <NA>                    0
2           52.67305                  FALSE                <NA>                    <NA>                    0
3           52.67305                  FALSE                <NA>                    <NA>                    0
4           52.37271                  FALSE                <NA>                    <NA>                    1
5           52.36014                  FALSE                <NA>                    <NA>                    0
6           52.29020                  FALSE                <NA>                    <NA>                    0
7                 NA                     NA                <NA>                    <NA>                    8
8           52.10300                  FALSE                <NA>                    <NA>                    1
9           52.34731                  FALSE                <NA>                    <NA>                    0
10          52.35427                  FALSE                <NA>                    <NA>                    0
11          52.36013                  FALSE                <NA>                    <NA>                    0
12          52.35298                  FALSE                <NA>                    <NA>                    0
13          52.36223                  FALSE      020 - 626 45 2                    <NA>                    1
14          52.37452                   TRUE                <NA>                    <NA>                    0
15          52.37190                  FALSE        020-626-4002                  1011EC                    0
16          52.35798                  FALSE                <NA>                    <NA>                    0
17          52.36328                  FALSE                <NA>                    <NA>                    0
18          52.35243                  FALSE                <NA>                    <NA>                    0
19          52.16282                  FALSE                <NA>                    <NA>                    1
20          52.34951                  FALSE                <NA>                    <NA>                    0
21          52.36355                  FALSE                <NA>                    <NA>                    0
22          52.09256                  FALSE        030 236 8466                    <NA>                    0
23          52.36859                  FALSE                <NA>                    <NA>                    6
24           0.00000                  FALSE                <NA>                    <NA>                    2
25          52.35920                  FALSE                <NA>                    <NA>                    0
```

Comment: I seem to recall that **leaflet** has problems with NAs in the coordinate columns. Does it work if you delete those rows with no coordinates?

Comment: @TimSalabim I see more points indeed, I used `vals <- apply(cbind(complete.cases(data$results.venue.lon), complete.cases(data$results.venue.lat)), 1, all)`, which leaves 580 rows. Still not even close to that amount of points rendered unfortunately

***Edit: I now see this replaces those with 0.0000 values, probably has problems with those too***

Comment: Is there a chance you can share your data? It's kinda hard to guess what's going on...

Comment: @TimSalabim Sure, it's meetupdata. Might be shitty formatted now but I selected some entries. As you see there is one there record which has NA for `results.venue.lon` and `results.venue.lat`. I'm guessing this is where it goes wrong. With the function I applied above these values are replaced by 0.0000 but that won't help

Comment: how about you create an index of the NA coordinates `ind <- is.na(data[["results.venue.lon"]]) | is.na(data[["results.venue.lat"]])` and then delete those rows from your data `data <- data[!ind, ]`

Comment: @TimSalabim Seems to return the same as first, so actually more points than 6 but way less than it should

Comment: Sorry, but without the original data I don't think I can help you any further.

Comment: @TimSalabim Thanks anyways, I don't think this is the problem .. all the NA and 0.000000 values are filtered out now, but it's still not good so

Comment: use dput() to add a subset of your dataset to your post.

Answer (score 2):

Leaflet will stop parsing data points when it hits the first error. To see all the points on your map, you will need to remove all of the NA values:

```
data <- data[!is.na(data$lat), ]
```